# Opening a floating menu (context menu) in Android?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-contextmenu

I created a new menu, named drmenu.xml. It works correctly when i press menu button, but I need to open a context menu when the user press the button.
The below code the button just show a toast.

this is my xml layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MenuCall"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MenuCall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/imageiew6" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my java code:

```
    final LinearLayout callback_var = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuCall);
    registerForContextMenu(callback_var);
    callback_var.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is repeated",      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            openContextMenu(callback_var);
        }
```

Comment: What are you exactly doing? MenuCall is an ImageView and you're casting it to LinearLayout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want create a context Menu, you have to call the method `registerForContextMenu()` passing it the View that should be associated with the context menu.

For example, supposing to associate the context menu with a Button:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
registerForContextMenu(button);
```

which can be called in the onCreate() of your Activity. Then, inside the same activity, you need to override the `onCreateContextMenu()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_context_menu, menu);
}
```

Then you have to implement `onContextItemSelected()`, for triggering the proper action when a item inside the context menu is pressed:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.first_action:
            // your first action code
            return true;
        case R.id.second_action:
            // your second action code
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now the long press click on the button opens the context menu you defined in the `your_context_menu.xml` file.

Consider that opening the context menu with a long press is compliant with the Android standard UI, however If you want your context menu to appear on a simple tap you can look [here the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981882/1584654)

**NOTE:** 
As said [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#attributes)

> An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be
>   unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often
>   be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when
>   possible).

Answer (score 0):

as Joseph82 said for context menu we can use that way . and i find for use option menu we i can use blow code :
in Oncreate Method write this :

```
    final LinearLayout callback_var = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuCall);
    callback_var.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater mnu = getMenuInflater();
    mnu.inflate(R.menu.darunamamenu, menu);
    return true;
}


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.firstpage:

            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case R.id.setting:
            Intent Settingact = new Intent(G.currentActivity, SettingActivity.class);
            G.currentActivity.startActivity(Settingact);
            G.currentActivity.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.regalarm:
            Intent RegAlarm = new Intent(G.currentActivity, alarmsetter.class);
            G.currentActivity.startActivity(RegAlarm);
            G.currentActivity.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.inform:
            Intent inform = new Intent(G.currentActivity, ActivityInformation.class);
            G.currentActivity.startActivity(inform);
            G.currentActivity.finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```