# Floating context menu on button click inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, contextmenu, android-context, android-menu

In my app I have created few buttons in one fragment which will redirect to several activity based on the click. Now if user click button1, they will get a floating context menu conataing the list of the comapny, such as company1, compan2...etc. I have followed this post [Opening a floating menu (context menu) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146818/opening-a-floating-menu-context-menu-in-android) to develop this feature in my app. But the problem is that this code is implemented in Activity, where in my case I want ti implement it in Fragment. I wrote the code but nothig happen with the button click. Now how can I generate this menu on button click

My contextmenu is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/company_1"
    android:title="@string/company_1"></item>

<item android:id="@+id/company_2"
android:title="@string/company_2"></item>

<item android:id="@+id/company_3"
android:title="@string/company_3"></item>

<item android:id="@+id/company_4"
    android:title="@string/company_4">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/company_5"
    android:title="@string/company_5"></item>

<item android:id="@+id/company_6"
    android:title="@string/company_6">
</item>
```

My Fragment Class is

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Button button1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(button);
    Button button2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button3=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
        this.getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextmenu_company,menu);
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.company_1:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"caompany1code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.company_2:
           ......
        case R.id.company_3:
            .....
        case R.id.company_4:
           ....
            return true;
        case R.id.company_5:
            .....
            return true;
        case R.id.company_6:
           .....
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"My colleagues clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "News clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Navigator clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }

}
```

In MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Set the fragment initially
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   .....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found something here :

Try this in your fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
if(v.getId()==R.id.button1{getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextmenu_company,menu);
}
}
```

You are also calling this wrong:

```
//Instead of button use button1.
registerForContextMenu(button1);
```

Maybe this will help.

Comment: it is showing expression expected in menu R.menu.contextmenu_company,menu

Comment: Call the super method too just like you did. Juat change the registerforcontextmenu and it is supposed work on long click.

Comment: I did this. but nothing happens in my button 1

Answer (score 0):

You did use

> onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

in your Activity but you are trying to use

> onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
>   ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)

in your fragment.

Use onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in your fragment as well and set setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your onCreateView method.

Comment: Yes. I have done that. but still it is not shwing. I have updated my code

Comment: Also I want to get a pop up menu/context menu on button click. that is why I use on create context menu

Comment: You have to set setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your onCreateView() not in your onCreateOptionsMenu()! What you want seems to be a PopupMenu. Have a look on [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)